# Как выложить приложение ios на сайт

Tags: ios, swift

Я создал свое приложение на ios , но выкладывать его в appstore не хочу.

У меня есть сайт куда я его должен выложить.

В интернете есть сайты которые распространяют свои приложения так(вот [пример](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-76603052&p=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_iPhone%3F) ).

Информацию как так сделать я не нашел, плюс я не понимаю как мне выгрузить из x-code готовое .ipa приложение.

Помогите прояснить со всем этим ситуацию

Comment: хороший вопрос, кстати. Человек даже пример приводит, чтоб доказать, что такое возможно и широко используется. Плюс как мы все помним, пока apple не купил testflight, они использовали примерно такую же схему - установи сертификат разработчика, и скачивай прилаги в свое удовольствие.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается через `[Apple Developer Enterprise Program][1]`, покупаете подписку, создаете билд, далее закидываете его к себе на сервер и [создаете `.plist`](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808598-iOS-Creating-an-Installation-Link-for-Your-Enterprise-App) фаил с нужными настройками, приделываете на сайте линк на `.plist` и все готово, пользователь нажимает на ссылку и устанавливает приложение.

Comment: Enterprise аккаунты Apple просто так не раздает всем подряд (особенно сейчас), нужно реально быть крупной компанией, существующей уже несколько лет, иметь DUNS-number...

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, конечно, старый, но, вдруг, кому пригодится?

Во-первых, нужно определиться, кто пользователи этого приложения? И сколько их?
Во-вторых, нужно четкое понимание про непринятие AppStore - вы просто не хотите это делать (жалко 99$ и др.), или Apple в принципе не пропустит ваше приложение в магазин?

Кроме, как через AppStore, приложение можно установить на устройство таким образом:

1. Джейлбрейк. Плюсы и минусы давно уже расписаны, повторять не будем.
2. Иметь аккаунт разработчика за 99$ и использовать сервис Apple TestFlight. Можно сделать тестовую сборку и пригласить внешних тестировщиков. Сборка будет работать 90 дней, потом нужно будет делать новую.
3. Иметь аккаунт разработчика за 99$, внести [UDID](https://skalolaskovy.ru/ios/257-udid) всех устройств, на которые будет выполняться установка (до 100 шт, менять - раз в год можно) в список "своих" на сайте developer.apple.com.
   Создать сертификаты и профили.
   С помощью xCode сделать Adhoc-сборку и получить ipa-файл. Устанавить приложение можно с помощью:
   а) iTools, iMazing или подобных программ, подключив девайс кабелем к компьютеру.
   б) загрузить полученный ipa-файл на сайт DIAWI.COM и отправить ссылку тем, кто должен установить приложение. Внимание! ссылка долго не живет, если что, придется заново загружать.
   в) на собственном сайте реализовать функционал для установки - нужен платный SSL-Сертификат (LetsEncrypt вроде бы не подходит) и немного повозиться - настроить и отладить (у Apple есть документация). Народ заходит по ссылке на web-страницу и устанавливают. НО только те, чьи UDID были изначально вписаны. При смене устройства (купил новое), программу не установишь, пока не сделаешь новую сборку (если еще есть квота по UDID).
   Еще один минус - приложение будет работать, пока не истек срок действия профиля (максимум - 1 год).
4. Иметь аккаунт Enterprise-разработчика. Ситуация - аналогичная п.3, только нет ограничений по количеству устройств, и не нужно добавлять UDID на сайте Apple.developer.com.

Но Enterprise аккаунты Apple просто так не раздает всем подряд (особенно сейчас - после покупки сервиса TestFlight), нужно реально быть крупной компанией, существующей уже несколько лет и с пеной у рта доказывать, что вам это 100500% нужно.
Enterprise аккаунт Apple может заблокировать, если с его помощью будут распространяться приложения направо и налево, так как в правилах написано, что можно только своих нужд.
Многим мелким компаниям-разработчикам Apple отказывает в этом, предлагают использовать TestFlight.
Некоторые разработчики, которые используют в приложениях технологии и/или принципы, не одобренные Apple, пытаются распространять их с помощью Enterprise. Похоже, что данная тема весьма востребована в узких кругах, так как за Enterprise-сертификат и Distribution-профиль или за Enterprise-аккаунт разработчика некоторые люди готовы заплатить не малые деньги:

[image: Enterprise аккаунт Apple]

Лично мое мнение - хорошенько подумать и, если какой-то функционал или контент приложения нужно ограничить для всех пользователей AppStore, то это можно, в принципе, реализовать. И зачастую это будет менее трудоемко, чем использовать иные варианты.

Answer (score 1):

На английской версии написано как можно достать .ipa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6

Да, для этого нужно будет сначала создать Developer и Distribution сертификаты, подписать с помощью своего провижен профайла, а потом выгрузить.
Ну а далее, самый просто способ, это выгрузить в какое нибудь облако .ipa файл, предоставить инструкцию по установке вместе, скажем, с архивом вашего .ipa + README.txt, где будет написано как установить через iTunes, ну и красивенько предоставить ссылку для скачивания с облака на сайте, либо если у вашего сайта есть хранилище, то помещаете туда и предоставляете URL.